# Google Cloud Project won't delete

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I made a Google Cloud project to test a few things out. The main one being DataPrep. Then I decided I'd do something else for a bit and tried to delete the project.

I opened up the Google Cloud Shell and typed:

```
gcloud projects delete <project_name>
```

and then typed Y for Yes and now it is just hung there doing nothing at all. It doesn't really matter I guess but it is annoying having an old project hanging around I can't get rid of.

I've tried with billing enabled and disabled but neither seem to make a difference. I was using the shell from within the Console website by the way.

Does anyone have any idea why it is taking so long to delete this project?

Comment: I would like to suggest you to check few things:
1. That your account have ownership on this project
2. Update gcloud 
3. Try gcloud alpha projects delete or gcloud beta  projects delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should follow these steps

> To shut down a project using the Cloud Platform Console:
>
> Open the Settings page in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
>
> Click Select a project.
>
> Select a project you wish to delete
> and click Open.
>
> Click Delete Project.
>
> Enter the Project ID and click Shut down.